# Permalinks that go to a specific template

Tags: permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

This is actually my first question here, so hello to everybody in this community!

I have developed a theme with a custom post type and a template (lets call it "my_template.php") that shows posts of this custom post type in an archive-like fashion.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make a permalink in the navigation of the site that goes to a specific template (like "my_template.php") and ignoring the wp template hierarchy.

How could one do that?

Note: I've already checked out [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25008/make-permalink-go-to-specific-template), but that one didn't really help and provided only a workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "ignoring the wp template hierarchy"?

Comment: What I mean by that is usually if you are creating a custom post type, wordpress follows the template hierarchy e.g. it looks first for single-{custom-post-name}.php, then archive-{custom-post-name} etc and then at the end it falls back to index.php . What I wanted to achieve is avoiding that altogether and just give my custom post type a template to which I could refer to via a permalink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see if a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) fits your needs.
Create a Page with the desired permalink, then set its page template to "my_template.php", and you're good!